# PHP: strlen() not functioning...At all

Tags: php, forms, strlen

I've tried looking at other answers, but all I come across is people placing their comparison operators in the wrong direction. Not the case here. Below is a simplified version of my code. This code does not return the error I believe it *SHOULD*.

I'm trying to determine if a string, in this case a password, meets a minimum length requirement. However, it never gives the error it should, regardless of the string I put in. As a means of debugging, I tried inputting a simple string, "hi" into strlen() and told it to give an error if it was less than 6 bytes long. However, even that wouldn't return as I wanted it to.

I feel like I'm missing something silly. Help?

```
<?php
$Email = mysql_real_escape_string(Trim($_POST['Email']));
$Password = "hi";

// check fields
$error = false;
if(empty($Email)) $error = true;
if(strlen(utf8_decode($Password)) < 6) $error = true;

if($error != false) header("Location: index.php?error=true");


// store user to database
$success = insert_dbUser(new User($Email, $Password));

// redirect to success page 
if ($success) {
    header("Location: index.php?success=true");
}
else header("Location: index.php?error=existinguser");
?>
```

Comment: For the record, I tried this both with and without the utf8_decode with no difference.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Though this doesn't address the question in the slightest, thank you for the advice! I just know mysql, I've never worked with anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to end the script after sending location headers:

```
if ($error) {
    header("Location: index.php?error=true");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Please do not use relative URI's inside the header() function

Comment: @RobB It *does* address OP's question. The script is failing because of multiple location headers.

Comment: Looks like that did it! Thank you. I am, however, curious about why this code worked and caught an error if the email was empty, but not for the password.

Comment: Note that you should really be explicitly returning a redirect status here as well.  The `Location` header is only meaningful when it is used with something in the 300 range or a 201 IIRC.

Comment: @RMartin I would guess that `insert_DbUser` failed when there was no email. Maybe you have constraints on the email field in your table?

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie It's officially allowed now in [HTTPbis](http://tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/).

Comment: I do have separate constraints. That may have been it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the syntax of your 'if' statements, as two of them have neither a colon ':' nor curly brackets'{ //do stuff }'. The else needs whatever is to happen 'else' to be in curly brackets. I may be mistaken, but the unusual syntax you have there is what stands out to me. As well as the need for exit statements.